# Turning off hibernate logging console output

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

I'm using hibernate 3 and want to stop it from dumping all the startup messages to the console. I tried commenting out the stdout lines in log4j.properties but no luck. I've pasted my log file below. Also I'm using eclipse with the standard project structure and have a copy of log4j.properties in both the root of the project folder and the bin folder.

```
### direct log messages to stdout ###
#log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### direct messages to file hibernate.log ###
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=hibernate.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### set log levels - for more verbose logging change 'info' to 'debug' ###

log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout

#log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug

### log HQL query parser activity
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=debug

### log just the SQL
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

### log JDBC bind parameters ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=info
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=debug

### log schema export/update ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug

### log HQL parse trees
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug

### log cache activity ###
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=debug

### log transaction activity
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=debug

### log JDBC resource acquisition
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug

### enable the following line if you want to track down connection ###
### leakages when using DriverManagerConnectionProvider ###
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider=trac5
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that Hibernate 4+ uses JBOSS logging.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try to set more reasonable logging level. Setting logging level to `info` means that only log event at `info` or higher level (`warn`, `error` and `fatal`) are logged, that is `debug` logging events are ignored.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

or in [XML version](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) of log4j config file:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
```

See also [log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: How do you do this in the XML version?

Comment: You can apply this to all packages in org.hibernate by doing the above, or if you want different levels for different packages within hibernate, you can specify those packages the same way.

Comment: This seems logical, but still does not work for me (Spring 3.0.5, Hibernate 3.5.6, sf4j-log4j bridge). I still get about 100 lines of 'INFO' comments on Hibernate startup each time. So this might not work for everyone.

Comment: @Twisted Pear: set your logging level to WARN. Then you wont get INFO messages.

Comment: Followup since this was never adequately resolved: Hibernate, even still in 4.3.0.Final, has lots of hardcoded `System.out.println()` calls.

Comment: In my case I disabled all hibernate logs setting the level to "fatal" and I'm logging manually what is important

Comment: how do i do the same in log4j2 .properties file ?

Answer (score 110):

Important notice: the property (part of hibernate configuration, NOT part of logging framework config!)

```
hibernate.show_sql
```

controls the logging *directly* to STDOUT bypassing any logging framework (which you can recognize by the missing output formatting of the messages). If you use a logging framework like log4j, **you should *always* set that property to false** because it gives you no benefit at all.

That circumstance irritated me quite a long time because I never really cared about it until I tried to write some benchmark regarding Hibernate.

**Spring**

(tested with spring-boot 3.0.6 and hibernate 5.6.15)

If you're using Spring Boot with properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
```

Comment: I had to set this property in my Hibernate (i.e., `hibernate.xml`) configuration, as opposed to my logging configuration.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: is there a way to have this logging to not bypass pass my logging framework but to actually use it? I'm seeing some exceptions sent to the stdout which I would like to log.

Comment: With my Spring boot project I added this in a profile YML conf file. But it didn't worked, just like the others posts on this thread... Hibernate logs keep being writted no matter what I specify. Can it be handled somewhere else than the Logback config, application yaml file and pom.xml ?

Comment: spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: false

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot with properties file: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false`

Answer (score 37):

Executing:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

before hibernate's initialization worked for me.

**Note:** the line above will turn *every* logging off (`Level.OFF`). If you want to be less strict, you can use

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

that is silent enough. (Or check the `java.util.logging.Level` class for more levels).

Comment: This worked for me: `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);`

Comment: where exactly does this code come into the picture? Any stub or class illustration?

Comment: Just run it anywhere before hibernate's initialization, e.g. right at the start of a `main` function, o a `@BeforeClass` of a test.

Answer (score 17):

You can disabled the many of the outputs of hibernate setting this props of hibernate (hb configuration) a false:

```
hibernate.show_sql
hibernate.generate_statistics
hibernate.use_sql_comments
```

But if you want to disable all console info you must to set the logger level a NONE of FATAL of class `org.hibernate` like Juha say.

Comment: What if I want to generate statistics, but not log?

Answer (score 7):

I finally figured out, it's because the Hibernate is using slf4j log facade now, to bridge to log4j, you need to put log4j and slf4j-log4j12 jars to your lib and then the log4j properties will take control Hibernate logs.

My pom.xml setting looks as below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Actually you can make Hibernate use slf4j explicitly by adding `-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j` to your VM options. I wrote an article on the topic: https://medium.com/@scadge/how-to-enable-hibernate-logging-dc11545efd3d

Answer (score 6):

For disabling `Hibernate:select` message in log, it is possible to set the property into `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`:

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who don't want elegant solutions, just a quick and dirty way to stop those messages, here is a solution that worked for me (I use Hibernate 4.3.6 and Eclipse and no answers provided above (or found on the internet) worked; neither log4j config files nor setting the logging level programatically)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //magical - do not touch
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    org.jboss.logging.Logger logger = org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate");
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.WARNING); //or whatever level you need

    ...
}
```

I used it in a tutorial program downloaded from [this site](http://www.journaldev.com/2882/hibernate-tutorial-for-beginners-using-xml-annotations-and-property-configurations)

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do is to figure out which logging framework is actually used.

Many frameworks are already covered by other authors above. In case you are using Logback you can solve the problem by adding this *logback.xml* to your classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN"/>
</configuration>
```

Further information: [Logback Manual-Configuration](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

**To disable printing hibernate queries in logs, just add this to your `application.properties`**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@DataJpaTest` annotation from [Spring Boot Test Auto-Configure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.autoconfigured-spring-data-jpa) enables SQL output by default. To disable SQL output when using that annotation in tests, change

```
@DataJpaTest
public class MyTestClass {
    ...
}
```

to

```
@DataJpaTest(showSql = false)
public class MyTestClass {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the "debug" to "info" and it worked. Here is what I did:

Before:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
```

After:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, R
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts of hibernate logging you can control based on the logger hierarchy of the hibernate package (more on logger hierarchy [here](https://www.journaldev.com/7128/log4j2-example-tutorial-configuration-levels-appenders)).

```
    <!-- Log everything in hibernate -->
    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Logger>

    <!-- Log SQL statements -->
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
      <AppenderRef ref="File" />
    </Logger>

    <!-- Log JDBC bind parameters -->
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
      <AppenderRef ref="File" />
    </Logger>
```

The above was taken from [here](https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-log4j-2-configuration-example).

Additionally you could have the property `show-sql:true` in your configuration file since that supersedes the logging framework settings. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012333/turn-off-hibernate-logging-to-console/59685881#59685881).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to stop by adding those 2 lines

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.orm.deprecation=error

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error
```

Bellow is what my *log4j.properties* looks like, i just leave some commented lines explaining the log level

```
# Root logger option
#Level/rules TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL.
#FATAL: shows messages at a FATAL level only
#ERROR: Shows messages classified as ERROR and FATAL
#WARNING: Shows messages classified as WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL
#INFO: Shows messages classified as INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL
#DEBUG: Shows messages classified as DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL
#TRACE : Shows messages classified as TRACE,DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL
#ALL : Shows messages classified as TRACE,DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL
#OFF : No log messages display


log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, console

log4j.logger.main=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.orm.deprecation=error
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error

#######################################
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.file.file=logs/MyProgram.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

# set file size limit
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=50


#############################################
# Direct log messages to System Out
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace slf4j-jdk14-xxx.jar with slf4j-log4j12-xxx.jar. If you have both, delete slf4j-jdk14-xxx.jar. Found this solution at https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=999623

Comment: great, this works. I could use `log4j.properties` configuration; `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF`

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of logger output in console try this.

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

loggerContext.stop();
```

These statements disabled all the console outputs from logger.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had added the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

which was not necessary. I removed it and everything works perfectly