# Turn off hibernate logging to console

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j

When running my Spring/Hibernate application I see the following unwanted output on the console:

```
Hibernate: select securityus0_.ID ....
Hibernate: select securityus0_.ID ....
Hibernate: select securityus0_.ID ....
Hibernate: select securityus0_.ID ....
```

I have configured my Log4j logger like so:

```
   <logger name="org.hibernate">
     <level value="FATAL"/>
   </logger>

   <category name="STDOUT">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>
   <category name="STDERR">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>   

   <!-- for all other loggers log only info and above log messages -->
   <root>
      <priority value="WARN"/> 
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
   </root>
```

How do I silence these messages?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you're seeing those SQL statements because somewhere in your Hibernate config the property "hibernate.show_sql" is set to true. Find that setting and change to false.

Comment: I do not have a hibernate configuration file. I'm using hibernate annotations together with Spring 3.

Comment: Check the part of your Spring configuration where you declare the SessionFactory. The 'hibernate.show_sql' property is normally set inside the SessionFactory's 'hibernateProperties'.

Comment: The `hibernate.show_sql` property may also be set in `AbstractJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean)` / `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean)`

Answer (score 5):

If you have a persistence.xml file try there.  That's where I found it.

Comment: I had `<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>` there. Can be INFO, CONFIG, etc., for less logging.

Answer (score 5):

Set the below to false in applications.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

it will turn off Hibernation messages.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by adding:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
```

in the persistence.xml file, this is if you have one

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `application.yml` file based on your configuration you may find the property `show-sql:true` under the `jpa` property.