# How to force Jboss 7.1.1 to use slf4j?

Tags: jboss7.x, slf4j

My question is more related to "[Force Jboss logging to use of SLF4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733369/force-jboss-logging-to-use-of-slf4j)" but couldn't find more details in it so i am posting it here again. How to make slf4j work, if one of my class calls for slf4j i get the below error. Since jboss 7.1.1 already have slf4j module, what else i need add to make it work.

```
20:20:31,565 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

20:20:31,572 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

20:20:31,578 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-8) SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to force anything. slf4j is a logging facade. JBoss AS provides a bridge between slf4j and the JBoss Log Manager. All you need to do to get it to work is

1. Make sure you don't include the slf4j API library in your deployment
2. Also make sure you don't include an slf4j bridge in your deployment

Other than those two things there souldn't be anything else to do.