# Hibernate System.err console logging

Tags: java, hibernate, slf4j

Hibernate appears to be logging normal information to `System.err`.  A few examples are:

```
System.err: Sep 03, 2013 10:41:55 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
System.err: Sep 03, 2013 10:41:55 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
System.err: Sep 03, 2013 10:41:55 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
System.err: Sep 03, 2013 10:41:55 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
System.err: Sep 03, 2013 10:42:02 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
```

There are about 70 of these in total.  My logging setup is as follows:

```
log4j-over-slf4j.jar
slf4j-api.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
```

I know that slf4j-simple, [per the SLF4J Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html), `"outputs all events to System.err. Only messages of level INFO and higher are printed."`

Knowing this, I set the `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile` system property to `System.out` as [specified in the SimpleLogger docs](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html).

This didn't change any behavior, however, and I am still getting 70+ Hibernate System.err logs.

Is there any way to configure Hibernate to not output to `System.err`?  The problem is that these `System.err` messages are being interpreted as WARNs while they are only informational messages.

Comment: are you **really** setting the property?

Comment: To my knowledge, yes.  I did some testing when the property was not set (default to System.err) and I received more logs that had been output to `System.err`.  After setting the property those log statements went away but the Hibernate ones were still there.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Hibernate 4.x uses JBoss for its logging this was causing the issue.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639997/how-do-you-configure-logging-in-hibernate-4) helped the most and the solution was to set the system property `org.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j`.

This enabled `slf4j-simple` to pick up all of the Hibernate `System.err` outputs.  Using the system property mentioned in the original thread you could change the `System.err` outputs to `System.out`.