# How to log with SLF4J/logback in Tomcat + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, logging

So, I'm deploying a web app which use Hibernate 4.3.6. and Tomcat 7.
I'm trying to use SLF4J as logging abstract layer to log. However, I have many issues and doubts.
First of all, both Hibernate and Tomcat come yet with different logging frameworks, jboss-logging and juli respectively (even if I can't find juli on the libraries)
So, I think I have to install the bridge from these frameworks to SLF4J. 
For Hibernate, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19488546/2326627) answer, a solution could be to use a SystemProperty. However, if I don't set this,

> it tries jboss, then log4j, then slf4j (only if logback used) and fallback to jdk.
>   So, maybe this is what I want: don't set the SystemProperty and leaves it choose slf4j.

For Tomcat, I think I have to simply add the jul-to-slf4j and tomcat-juli jars to the build path.
So, at this moment, I have this jars on the build path:

- slf4j-api-1.7.7
- logback-classic-1.1.2
- logback-core-1.1.2
- tomcat-juli-7.0.42
- jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7

(I've deleted jboss-logging and the default and old slf4j coming with hibernate, but not tomcat-logging)
Also, I've added this xml file inside a package in my project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug = "true">

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/var/lib/tomcat7/MyApp/MyLog.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

but I haven't linked it to any resource at all. Have I to declare this log configuration somewhere in web.xml?
To call SLF4J inside one of my resources, I simply put these lines

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServlet.class);
...
LOG.debug("I'm logging");
```

However, nothing works. I continue to have messages from Tomcat logger, while Hibernate complains that it doesn't have a logger; at the same time, I can't see any log coming from slf4j/logback.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.server.controller.servlet.ContainerContext
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2944)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:192)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
```

The error message stay the same even if I add "-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j" to the VM arguments. 
So, how can I solve the problem?

---

**EDIT**

Adding back jboss-logging to classpath the error disappeared. Problem is that now I have a lot of messages coming from logback, jboss-logging and juli. Also, no file is created until now, even if I specified one in logback.xml; instead, it continues to write to the console using the default pattern (indeed, it doesn't print the day as specified in logback.xml).
This is an example of log output, where you can easily identify messages coming from the different loggers (logback start with the hour, jboss-logging start with Hibernate: and juli start with the debug level)

```
16:50:01.331 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        subforums0_.parent_sub_forum as parent_s3_1_0_,
        subforums0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        subforums0_.id as id1_1_1_,
        subforums0_.parent_sub_forum as parent_s3_1_1_,
        subforums0_.title as title2_1_1_ 
    from
        subforum subforums0_ 
    where
        subforums0_.parent_sub_forum=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        subforums0_.parent_sub_forum as parent_s3_1_0_,
        subforums0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        subforums0_.id as id1_1_1_,
        subforums0_.parent_sub_forum as parent_s3_1_1_,
        subforums0_.title as title2_1_1_ 
    from
        subforum subforums0_ 
    where
        subforums0_.parent_sub_forum=?
16:50:01.332 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl - Preparing collection intializer : [pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum.subforums#11]
16:50:01.337 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.l.i.CollectionLoadContext - 1 collections were found in result set for role: pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum.subforums
16:50:01.337 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.l.i.CollectionLoadContext - Collection fully initialized: [pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum.subforums#11]
16:50:01.337 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.l.i.CollectionLoadContext - 1 collections initialized for role: pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum.subforums
16:50:01.338 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.l.c.p.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer - Done loading collection
16:50:01.338 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing
16:50:01.339 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
16:50:01.346 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
16:50:01.361 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.Collections - Collection found: [pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum.subforumThreads#11], was: [pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum.subforumThreads#11] (uninitialized)
16:50:01.361 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.engine.internal.Collections - Collection found: [pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum.subforums#11], was: [pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum.subforums#11] (initialized)
16:50:01.362 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
16:50:01.362 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 2 collections
16:50:01.364 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
16:50:01.366 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.internal.util.EntityPrinter - pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.forum.shared.model.entities.Subforum{subforumThreads=<uninitialized>, subforums=[], subforumParent=null, subforumId=11, subforumTitle=Main}
16:50:01.367 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
16:50:01.373 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
16:50:01.373 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
Dec 06, 2014 4:50:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 06, 2014 4:50:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5850 ms
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Deploying the app on the system installation folder of Tomcat (instead of the one used by Eclipse), all the juli files are written into catalina.[date].log, while the logs coming from jboss-logging and logback are written into catalina.out. It seems that the logback.xml file isn't recognized at all.

---

**EDIT 3**
Well, one of the problems seems to be with the position of logback.xml. I had put it in a subfolder, while it should be directly under WEB-INF/classes. Now it logs to the right directories. However, both Hibernate and Tomcat still continues to write their log messages to System.out (and as a result to catalina.out).

---

**EDIT 4**
Ok, I disabled Hibernate outputs to stdout deleting `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` from `hibernate.cfg.xml`.
Now, my question is: is it ok/desiderable that tomcat continues to print messages like

```
Dec 07, 2014 7:46:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

on the console?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that there are two issues with logging - Hibernate logging & tomcat logging

1. For hibernate you will have to include jboss-logging jar in your classpath because JBoss Logging is just a logging facade. To configure your loggers, e.g. use/add handlers, you need a log manager like JBoss Log Manager, the J.U.L. log manager, logback or log4j. 
   Just including this library should resolve your issue.
2. For tomcat logging, you might have to specify slf4j configuration in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties

   handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler

I assume you have named the xml file as logback.xml and placed it in the classpath.

Comment: to @stackdev also. Ok so I added back jboss-logging to classpath and the error disappeared. Problem is that now I have a lot of messages coming from logback, jboss-logging and juli. Also, I modified the logback.xml file a little bit trying to isolate the messages coming from logback, but no file is created. Instead, it continues to write to the console.
Also, I've yet modified the logging.properties file, but I don't think it is used now: I'm deploying the server using Eclipse inside workspace metadata.

Comment: About your problem of lot of messages, can you post a snapshot of the logs and the latest logback.xml to http://pastebin.com/ so that the problem can be understood correctly.

Comment: sorry, I had not written, but I added all the infos in the EDITs, while I directly modified the logback.xml

Answer (score 0):

jboss-logging is a transitive dependency of hibernate-core, so jboss-logging jar should be in the build path. Check Project>Deployment Assembly, and make sure maven dependencies are present there, it should look like

[image]

Also try Tomcat>Clean... .

Comment: Don't know if you read the comment under the other answers. Btw, thanks for your time. I think one of the problems is that the logback.xml file was inside a subfolder of WEB-INF/classes. However, I'm still having other issues: indeed, Hibernate continues to log its messages to stdout (and as a result on catalina.out).