# How to remove log from Hibernate itself?

Tags: hibernate, logging, log4j, slf4j

Hiberante generates many logs from itself (rather than my application code).e.g,

```
[main] WARN org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData - Potential problem found: The configured data type factory 'class o
June 21, 2015 12:57:03 下午 org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
```

If specifying print "WARN" log in slf4j.properites/log4s.properites, logging tools cannot distinguish which source(or component) generate the log?

How to remove these logs? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hibernate 4 has to be instructed to use slf4j/log4j (before Hibernate is used) via e.g. `System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19488546/3080094

Answer (score 0):

All relevant logging frameworks allow you to specify the log level per logger(hierarchy). So you can set the log level for everything to `INFO` and for `org.hibernate` to `ERROR`.

See the documentation of your logging tool of choice on how to specify the log level.

In log4j.properties It would look similar to this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR

log4j.appender.A1= ...
```