# How to disable hibernate logging in console?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to disable hibernate logging in my console , i tried the below.
The below code belongs to my app-config.xml:-

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" name="sourceFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myprojds"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproj" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The below code belongs to log4j.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

<appender name="appender1" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/opt/info_${current.date}.log"/>
    <param name="append" value="false"/>
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="2MB"/>
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="200"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %5p (%F:%M:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <priority value ="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="appender1"/>
</root>
<logger name="org.hibernate"  additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="appender1"/> 
    <level value="error" /> 
</logger>

 </log4j:configuration>
```

I am still not sure why i am seeing hibernate logs in the console. Please help

Comment: Can you post an example of the logs that you see in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer hibernate version the logging is done by using JBoss Logging as a bridge between many logger implementations. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639997/how-do-you-configure-logging-in-hibernate-4-to-use-slf4j) has a discussion on how to set slf4j in hibernate 4, but the problem is pretty similar. You may have to debug this [class](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logging/LoggerProviders.java) to check how hibernate is selecting it's logging provider. Maybe you are having a classpath problem (hibernate is not finding the log4j in classpath).
There is chance that you'll have to set some system property or create a service loader file (the first link has some hints on this) for hibernate to select the logging provider correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That is the configuration for a RollingFileAppender (log to files at /opt/info_${current.date}.log, not the console). See if there is a ConsoleAppender somewhere in your config. If there is no ConsoleAppender then you might be seeing console logs from system.out within the code itself.

Comment: I am seeing logs in my eclipse console , i shouldn't be seeing those , after i have set  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>