# SQL CREATE and INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE Application (
    studentID       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
    firstName       VARCHAR(10),
    lastName        VARCHAR(20),
    ic              VARCHAR(15),
    dateOfBirth     DATE,
    gender          CHAR(1),
    email           VARCHAR(20),
    applStatus      VARCHAR(10),
    homeAddress     VARCHAR(30),
    pinCode         INTEGER,
    country         VARCHAR(10),
    stated          VARCHAR(10),

    primary key (studentID)
);

INSERT INTO APPLICATION VALUES('15WAD04433','DANIEL','CHOO','961019-06-1783','19/10/1996','M','DC@HOTMAIL.COM','SUCCESSFUL','A 4710, LORONG ALOR AKAR 30',25250,'KUANTAN','PAHANG');
```

Error is [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 22007] The string representation of a date/time value is out of range.

Hi everyone, I am using "NetBeans IDE 8.2" to create a database but when i insert the date 19/10/1996 come out with an error. There is impossible the date of birth is 2016 year same as the current date and time, may i know what to do to set the date of birth back to 1996 without having the error?

Comment: This may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242000/sqlcode-181-the-string-representation-of-a-datetime-value-is-not-a-valid-dateti

Comment: never do INSERT INTO my_table values(...) __always__ specifies the columns that you are inserting to like INSERT INTO my_table(col1,col2,..) anway the problem with your date is thtat it should be '1996-10-19' or 1996/10/19

Comment: Yes the pattern should be 'YYYY-MM-DD', look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120433/php-mysql-insert-date-format

Comment: and please don't use needless tags theres no java here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html)

> Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, date parts must always be given in year-month-day order (for example, '98-09-04'), rather than in the month-day-year or day-month-year orders commonly used elsewhere (for example, '09-04-98', '04-09-98')

You need to change your date format `19/10/1996` to `1996-10-19`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the date to `'10/19/1996'` as the pattern is most likely month/day/year. You can also provide the month/day/year pattern for your situation: `TO_DATE('19/10/1996', 'DD/MM/YYYY')`