# Turn off hibernate logging on stdout

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jar, log4j

Please read complete question and then think of the possibility of being duplicate.

**I have gone through several question on stackoverflow and they suggested ways to turn off hibernate logging on `stdout`.**

I could successfully turn off hibernate logging on `stdout` when I use `maven` to run the jar file of my application (`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.flytxt.JobMonitor"`). This was achieved by using `log4j.prpoerties` file.

The output on `stdout` by using `maven` shown below:

[image]

But when I use the same jar file packaged by `maven` (can be found in the `target` subdirectory of the project directory), add all jars into the MANIFEST.MF manually and execute it (`java -jar JobMonitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`), I see too much DEBUG logging info of hibernate on `stdout` like show below:

```
root@fly-dt223:/home/rohit/workspace_dfe/JobMonitor/JobMonitor/daemon# java -jar JobMonitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
17:00:41.954 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
17:00:41.965 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@1ef8deca
17:00:41.965 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@1ef8deca
17:00:41.965 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@1ef8deca
17:00:41.966 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration numeric_boolean -> org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType@1ce2a846
17:00:41.967 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration true_false -> org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType@1ce7df90
17:00:41.967 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration yes_no -> org.hibernate.type.YesNoType@40d2a14b
17:00:41.968 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@2b6167ab
17:00:41.968 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@2b6167ab
17:00:41.968 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@2b6167ab
17:00:41.969 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration character -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@6ba47ef5
17:00:41.969 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration char -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@6ba47ef5
17:00:41.969 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Character -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@6ba47ef5
17:00:41.970 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@39614c6
17:00:41.971 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@39614c6
17:00:41.972 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@39614c6
17:00:41.973 [192.168.151.50] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration integer -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@1621a02b
```

My application uses `log4j.properties` and its content is shown below.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/hibernate.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=INFO
```

It appears that maven is loading `log4j.properties` file from either the jar file itself or from the other path.
Below are the locations of `log4j.properties` file within my project directory structure:

[image]
[image]

So, my question is: How can I stop hibernate to log on `stdout` and make it log into a file as pointed in the content of the file `log4j.properties` shown above when I use simply `java -jar JobMonitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` ?

I assume, it is likely that my application could not locate `log4j.properties` while using the command `java -jar JobMonitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning off hibernate logging console output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output)

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I could turn off logging onto `stdout` using maven executor but I could not turn it off when I use `java -jar JobMonitor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Some answers in the link you provide would work but I dont want my application to stop logging programmatically.