# Hibernate disable logging

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, intellij-idea, orm

I'm having problems with disabling hibernates logging system.
I tried creating a log4j.properties file and set the property rootLogger to false but it didn't do anything.

What i get in my console is:

```
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: Database/hibernate.cfg.xml
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: Database/hibernate.cfg.xml
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Database/Entities/User.hbm.xml
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gameserver]
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:52 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:53 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
Jul 04, 2015 8:01:53 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

How can i disable all the messages to the output console?

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.2

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output?rq=1

Comment: @RC. That's for version 3, I am using 4. Not sure if there is a difference.

Comment: In the linked question someone posted some code with jboss logging and I think this is still valid. see also the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Root Logger to the ERROR level:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error
```

Make sure you have SLF4J and LOG4J in your classpath as Hibernate might fallback to using other logging frameworks instead.

Try adding a breakpoint in `org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders` when Hibernate starts to check the Logging provider.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a very similar situation, where I was trying to find a way to disable Hibernate's logging when creating an EntityManagerFactory during the start of my application. It also happened to me that none of the answers I found on StackOverflow work. I'm using Hibernate 5.2.10.Final, which uses jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.

I had to go to the extreme measure, or hack, of disabling all log messages by getting the "empty-named" `java.util.logging.Logger` and setting its level to `java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE` thus:

```java
private void disableLogging() {
  LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
  Logger logger = logManager.getLogger("");
  logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE); //could be Level.OFF
}
```

However, as this is the parent of all `Logger`s, this will also affect any other `Logger`s you are using. You may want to set the level (back) to another level afterwards.

Comment: This is a relevant solution in 2019. Great job on this eh as well as the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following dependencies in my maven in order to get rid of the logging. I am using Hibernate 4 and Log4j2

- log4j-api
- log4j-core
- log4j-jcl  // reverse bridge to log4j v1.x
- slf4j-simple
- jboss-logging  // without this it did not work

in your log4j2.xml

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false" level="error"/>
```

maven POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```