# how to turn off hiberrnate logging in jar application?

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging

I wan turn of hibenate and spring logs in my runable jar file.
I am using spring jpa framework. How it's work?.
I also try

```
LogManager.shutdown();
java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Do any of these answers work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output?rq=1

Comment: but i have no log4j.xml because it's jar

Comment: If you can make the code changes above, you can also add logging configuration files into the jar file, no?

Comment: no i added but it did't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF); 

org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);

LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
lc.getLogger("org").setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.ERROR);
```