# How to suppress hibernate messages in InteliJ Idea?

Tags: hibernate, logging, intellij-idea, persistence

How to suppress hibernate messages in InteliJ Idea ?

```
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: persistenceUnit
    ...]
січ. 26, 2018 3:57:34 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
січ. 26, 2018 3:57:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
січ. 26, 2018 3:57:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
```

Tried these options in `persistence.xml` with no result.

```
<property name="org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.level" value="error"/>
<property name="org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper" value="error"/>
<property name="java.util.logging.Logger.org.hibernate" value="error"/>
<property name="java.util.logging.Level" value="error"/>
<property name="org.hibernate.logging.level" value="error"/>
<property name="org.hibernate" value="error"/>
<property name="org.hibernate.level" value="error"/>
<property name="org.hibernate.internal.log" value="error"/>

<property name="log4j.logger.org.hibernate" value="error"/>
<property name="log4j.rootLogger" value="error"/>
<property name="hibernate.logging.parameters" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.sql" value="error"/>
```

Comment: What options did you try exactly? Please edit the question and add what you've tried so far.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/311445/2849346 might be helpful.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/311445/2849346 wasn't helpful :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using logging library like log4j, then you can add the following lines on configuration file –

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
```

You can also disable **hibernate.show_sql** option from hibernate configuration file

Comment: Disabling hibernate.show_sql do not turns off INFO output.