# I am trying to disable logging of hibernate queries

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to stop logging hibernate queries on different environments, for example when on the development machine I want to see all the hibernate queries on the Tomcat log console but on the production server I don't want to see them.
For now I have not tried any solution and am using (hibernate 2.1.1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off hibernate logging console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a query string with parameter values when using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/how-to-print-a-query-string-with-parameter-values-when-using-hibernate)

Comment: thanks @MatanShahar the link you shared helped i had to update my appliacation.yaml file and added hibernate:
            show_sql: true