# Disable Logging in Hibernate [JBOSS Environment]

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have used one jar file, within which I'm using hibernate. There I have a log4j properties file configured for its WARN,FATAL level log, but I'm still getting all the log, because of which performance is getting down.
I`m new to hibernate please let me know what should I do.
Below I have provided my log4j and hbm.cfg.xml file.

I`m calling the JAR file from a web application.

log4j.properties:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file, stdout


# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}//logs//logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=/home/jboss/SSS_DI_error.log

#log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logigng.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=30MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=FATAL
```

hbm.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> 
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <mapping class="com.integra.plugin.onlineEnrol.beans.EnrollmentDetails"/>
        <mapping class="com.integra.plugin.onlineEnrol.beans.CustomerIdentificationDetails"/>
        <mapping class="com.integra.plugin.onlineEnrol.beans.DedupKeyDetails"/>
        <mapping class="com.integra.plugin.onlineEnrol.beans.EnrollmentStatus"/>
    </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Please refer to :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Open standalone.xml of wildfly (WILD_FLY_HOME/standalone/configuration) and look for logging subsystem. You will see something like this .

Now there will be different logger. For disabling hibernate log just add this logger

```
<logger category="org.hibernate">
     <level name="OFF"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Where to find this file

Comment: Updated my answer